# Jenkins WORKSPACE Root Directory with forward slashes

Tags: jenkins, workspace, forward, slash

We have a problem regarding the Workspace Directory in Jenkins. When I set the Jenkins Workspace Root directory with forward slashes (i.e. "D:/Workspaces/TestProject1"), it converts it to the backward slashes while accessing the Jenkins built-in "WORKSPACE" environment variable. So this causes build failure issues in our project. Since our ant script requires a path with forward slashes only. I tried to inject a new environment variable in Env inject plugin and this solved the issue. Note also that our build is parameterized so I can't give a custom workspace folder. Any alternative solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to double the backward slashes?

`D:\\Workspaces\\TestProject1`

It should better for Ant.

Comment: it does not work since Jenkins implicitly converts the path to one backward slash only version. (i.e. D:\Workspaces\TestProject1) Besides ant is expecting a forward slashes path value in order to build.